# Two almost identical processes in Tibco

Tags: tibco, tibco-designer

I have two almost identical processes in Tibco that start with a Topic Subscriber. The only difference is the topic name.

How can I design one process so that it can be reusable?

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable for the topic name in your TIBCO designer project. Use this global variable as topic name in your subscriber (drag & drop global variable into the field).

By that you can deploy your project n times and just configure the topic name individually in the Administrator UI.

Hope that helps

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I want to run the same process for two different topics. How can I do that?

Comment: If your topics are all in a hierarchical structure that could work with one single process and a wildcard subscription. E.g. you have topic 1 (Name: topic.myContext.one) and topic 2 (Name: topic.myContext.two). Your subscriber subscribes to topic.myContext.* and will receive messages from both topics

Comment: Sounds good. Based on the topic name I also need to push the message to some other topic. But I guess I should use the message properties for this.

Comment: Ok if you use also TIBCO EMS as JMS server, you might let it do the "filter" job by itself if you only need to push messages into other topics it can be done with the bridge function internally of EMS (e.g. check out this feature here https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.3.0/doc/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=TIB_ems_users_guide/EMS.5.035.htm)